# Get image from webcam

Tags: c#, webcam

I'm trying to find the way for getting image (only image, not video stream) from webcam in managed C#. 
Usually people suggesting libraries, but they are old or commercial or under gpl.

How get image from webcam without third-party libraries?

**upd.:** thanks for Media Foundation, I shall use that.

Answer (score 3):

Web cameras are supposed to deliver video feeds, not stills. So the native API you might be interested in is the one for video capture, which are DirectShow and Media Foundation.

The one you would most likely want is DirectShow, but it is not well suited to be interfaced from managed code, so you will need a [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) which is open source wrapper. You typically start video streaming there and once you have a good image you stop the activity.

Or instead you might keep looking for a ready to use library which does the mentioned above for you.

One of DirectShow.NET samples does what you look for.

> DxSnap – Use DirectShow to take snapshots from the Still pin of a
>   capture device. Note the MS encourages you to use WIA for this, but if
>   you want to do in with DirectShow and C#, here's how.

It mentions WIA, however WIA API is not available for all (or any in recent OSes?) web cameras, WIA more targets device like scanners.

Other APIs are perhaps less suitable.

- VFW ("avicap32.dll") limits you to a subset of devices, is simple yet not well interfaced into managed code
- Media Foundation is not well available in earlier OS versions

Comment: DirectShow.NET under gpl, but I'm not.

Comment: No, it is not GPL. It is LGPL.

Comment: I see "gpl" and go away. Over.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this many years ago

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?344471-Vb.Net-WebCam-Class-(ICam)) in VB.net

You could easily port it to c#?

Answer (score 1):

Is avicap32.dll out of the question?

Otherwise I think this is a simple and straightforward way:

http://www.creativecodedesign.com/node/66

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/yougerthen/integrate-the-web-webcam-functionality-using-C-Sharp-net-and-com-part-viii/

Comment: Under which licence this library? 
Does it works on x64 system?

Comment: I believe avicap32.dll is a Windows assembly and comes in System32/SysWOW64. I know there has been issues with it in x64 but I also know people has gotten it to work.